# Path for getResourceAsStream in Android Project

Tags: java, android, jar, imageview, android-bitmap

I am trying to programmatically load a .png file but I am not sure what is the exact path I should be giving. I tried different paths that I think would get me to the resource but all return null:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("playstore.png");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
mStoreImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

If I understand correctly I cannot use resources as I am building a .jar. This is my project package structure displayed with Android Studio:
[image]

Comment: Why you don't use res folder? and drawable?

Comment: @blay added the clarification, I'm building a .jar which cannot have resources/res folder, correct/

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

You should use `Resources.openRawResource()`

e.g. if your Activity

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.playstore.png);
```

remember to put the file under `res/raw`

**Edit:**

In addition, android has it own method to get drawable (e.g. a png file) into Bitmap

Comment: I am building a .jar so cannot use resources? The only option seems to be what I described above?

Comment: You are asking a question on Android, and you have AndroidManifest.xml, are you sure you are building jar, but not a apk or android library?

Comment: I will convert the final product to a .jar with a gradle script. I have done this before, right now the concern is how to load an image without res folder

Comment: assuming that your `playstore.png` would be put into the a jar properly, it looks like it would be in `com/adscendmedia/videosdk/`, so you should run `getResourceAsStream("com/adscendmedia/videosdk/playstore.png")`

Comment: I have tried that path and it doesn't work. For testing I'm running the project from Android Studio directly (and not jar)

Comment: That's why I have said that you are not creating a jar, so it would not work, it is that simple.

Comment: I would suggest whatever you have to say put it in the form of an answer so when things work out for me I can mark the correct answer

Comment: @2cupsOfTech Have found a solution ?

Comment: @Zilk if I remember correctly I ended up converting images to Base64 encoded string as I only had few images to deal with. Either way .aar libraries is the way forward which will let you use resources, images etc. directly

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio Gradle projects read files from a separate resources directory in the same way as Maven does it.

Create a "resources" folder in Windows Explorer (Android Studio don't allow you to do that) and then recreate the package path and place files there, e.g.:

A class located at this path:

```
C:\...\app\src\main\java\com\adscendmedia\videosdk\AdscnedAPI.java
```

Read resource files from this path:

```
C:\...\app\src\main\resources\com\adscendmedia\videosdk\playstore.png
```